# get javascript dynimcally created control state

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I'm dynamically adding some rows to my ASP.NET table, I have several cells in each row and each cell contains a control which is dynamically created:

```
            var TD = document.createElement('td');
        var spanCheck = document.createElement("span");
        spanCheck.innerHTML = "<input type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Car'>mycheck";
        spanCheck.id = "newfoodcheck0";
        spanCheck.onclick = function () {

            if (spanCheck.checked)
                alert('checked');
            else
                alert('unchecked');
        };

        TD.appendChild(spanCheck);
```

I'm adding an onclick function for this span (which is rendered as a checkbox), I want to know when it is checked, but `if (spanCheck.checked)` doesn't work and I always get 'unchecked' in my alert, what is going wrong here? should I use spanCheck.checked or I should use `document.getElementById(spanCheck.id).checked`? I've tested it, but again with no luck! how can I know whether my checkbox is checked or know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `spanCheck` is not rendered as a checkbox. It *contains* a checkbox. Therefore, there's no such property `spanCheck.checked`.  There *is* a `spanCheck.children[0].checked` property, however.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is adding click event on spanCheck and checking for spanCheck.checked. However the checked property is on the input element which is the child of the spanCheck. You might want to do somewhat like this:

```
var TD = document.createElement('td');
    var spanCheck = document.createElement("span");
    spanCheck.innerHTML = "<input id='my_input' type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Car'>mycheck";
    spanCheck.id = "newfoodcheck0";
    spanCheck.onclick = function () {
            var input = document.getElementById('my_input');
            if (input.checked)
                alert('checked');
            else
                alert('unchecked');
        };
```

Also, I think you haven't inserted your TD into the body. So in the last line, you should use appendChild:

```
TD.appendChild(spanCheck);    
document.body.appendChild(TD);
```

Another thing, you should not attach onclick event on the span. You should attach the same on input element. The following code is doing the same:

```
var TD = document.createElement('td');
    var spanCheck = document.createElement("span");
    spanCheck.innerHTML = "<input id='my_input' type='checkbox' name='vehicle' value='Car'>mycheck";
    spanCheck.id = "newfoodcheck0";

    TD.appendChild(spanCheck);
    document.body.appendChild(TD);
    var input = document.getElementById('my_input');

    input.onclick = function () {
        if (input.checked)
            alert('checked');
        else
            alert('unchecked');
    };
```

Comment: Your answer is SOOOO much better than mine. I'm sorry I stole this one from you.

Comment: It's all right. The important thing is spreading the knowledge. Doesn't matter whose answer gets selected. If I can solve one's problem with what I know, that's all I need.